# Get price value in Webform submission

Tags: 8, commerce, webforms

I'm trying to create a webform that has an entity selection element linked to an entity reference view that has a selection of products from the commerce module listed. So far this has all been accomplished.

The entity selection entity displays the product names that you can choose from (unlimited values allowed)

I need to display the total price of the selected products on the confirmation price adding and giving me a total number of all the selected products within that entity selection element.

Is this possible? And where and how would I start?

(v. D8)

If helpful, here are machine names used in the entity reference:

(Commerce)
Product name:  field_product_name
SKU:  field_sku_feature
MSRP:  field_msrp

(Webform)
Entity select: sku_select

Comment: https://github.com/chx/webform_product

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for... Also, the reason I had been doing it in the example above is that I cannot add any modules or update any of the code at this time. I only have the frontend aspect to work with.